# is it possible to upload file form computer to project folder with just vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

uploading files in an old fashion would be to use HTML to grab the file and pass it to the PHP where it will be redirected (uploaded) to a folder of your choice (usually with move_upload_file() function). but will there be any way to upload a file with just javascript? what I mean by that is as the form submitted we will read the file inside the form, from javascript, and upload the file to the project folder (or any folder we want) without involving any serverside.

Comment: The browser JS runs on the client not the server so it has no access rights to copy files to the server.  The server needs to be running scripts or services that support accepting files from the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only server-side code can write to the server (although that server-side code can be written in any programming language, including JavaScript).

It would be a major security problem for the entire WWW if client-side JavaScript (and thus the client) could freely write to servers. The Google homepage would be defaced every half second.

The server-side code would receive the file via an HTTP request and that could be generated through a regular form submission or by JS (e.g. with the `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` APIs).